# running python file in PyCharm with external libraries or parameters

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a script connecting to Oracle DB while doing the job. This connection required external libraries from third party like Oracle common driver.

I found the way to add system viariables to the console in PyCharm so I can run my program properly in PyCharm python console. However when I try regular run (or debug) button it does not run complaining for lack of these libraries.
How can I define such variables/libraries to enable running my program directly?

Comment: In order to add external libraries to global or virtualenv. You simply download them at: File->Settings->Project: project_name -> Project Interpeter (then click 'plus' button and find what you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a virtual environment specifically for this project (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

After creating select this virtual environment and try to install the necessary libraries in File-> Settings-> Project Interpreter.

Comment: I think that PyCharm is creating such environment for me out of the box so  I don't have to do that. Bt the question remains: how to add all the libs I need there?

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, I am running cx_Oracle 5.3 with Django 1.11 and Oracle 11g. I defined the following environment variables in the run/debug configuration of pyCharm:

[image]

If you are running Windows then you will need to amend the paths accordingly...

Comment: When you update to cx_Oracle 6, note that cx_Oracle installation is significantly different, and also that macOS SIP means DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't useful.  See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-macos